# Alfresco webdav behind apache under jkmount

Tags: alfresco, webdav, mount

I'm trying to configure the access to an alfresco webdav directory.
Alfreso is in local ip 192.168.1.25. If I mount (with mount.davfs http:// 192.168.1.25 :8080) , it works ok.
If I configure jkmount in the apache server (in another local ip, 192.168.1.111), when I mount it (with mount.davfs http:// public /alfresco), it doesn't work. The mount error is:
mount.davfs: connection timed out two times;
trying one last time
mount.davfs: server temporarily unreachable;
mounting anyway

However, if I mount the URL with firefox, chrome, or Windows net share, it works ok.

I've tried different jkmount options, rewrites, etc., and with firefox and others it works ok, but it fails using mount (and I must use mount or any other command line tool).

Cadaver also fails.

Regards,

---

Thanks Heiko,

I've set up the virtual host with (Alfresco Server is in another server):

```
ProxyPass /alfresco ajp://192.168.1.25:8009/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco ajp://192.168.1.25:8009/alfresco

<Location /alfresco/webdav/ >
<Limit OPTIONS PROPFIND GET REPORT MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT CHECKOUT MKCOL MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK MERGE>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Limit>
</Location>
```

And the problem persists: I mount it with firefox (and chrome, etc.) ok, but it fails with mount.davfs or cadaver. It doesn't work with curl too.

In alfresco-global.properties, this lines are commented:

```
# URL Generation Parameters (The ${localname} token is replaced by the local server name)
#-------------
#alfresco.context=alfresco
#alfresco.host=${localname}
#alfresco.port=8080
#alfresco.protocol=http
#
#share.context=share
#share.host=${localname}
#share.port=8080
#share.protocol=http
```

Are they necessary?

Is there any other apache directive for this?

I also tried to offer the directory via apache with:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/alfresco/(.*)$ "http://192.168.1.25:8080/alfresco/$1"
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco/ "http://192.168.1.25:8080/alfresco/"
```

and

```
JkMount /alfresco/* alfresco configuring jk workers.properties with:

worker.list=alfresco

worker.alfresco.type=ajp13
worker.alfresco.host= 192.168.1. 25
worker.alfresco.port=8009
worker.alfresco.lbfactor=1
worker.alfresco.socket_keepalive=1
worker.alfresco.socket_timeout=300
```

And the results are the same: It works in navigators but not in linux console.

I've set apache logs in debug mode for this virtual hosts, and when I mount it with firefox, it writes the right info (ajp conections, etc) but when I try to mount from linux terminal, the logs are empty. This is like the conection doesn't work, but only from console...

Thanks for your help, I keep looking for solutions...

Comment: Does the rest of Alfresco work fine? i.e. is this an Alfresco WebDav specific problem, or a general one for your Alfresco using jkmount?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up virtual host like described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/472491/how-to-set-up-alfresco-share-behind-apache-reverse-proxy)?
Also you may need to set ProxyPreserveHost Directive or something similar depending on your apache mod (mod_http_ajp or mod_jk)

Comment: Well, the problem was solved. The network firewall has a rule that forbade the traffic between my test ubuntu terminal and public IP. The configuration ProxyPass /alfresco ajp://192.168.1.25:8009/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco ajp://192.168.1.25:8009/alfresco was OK, thank you